How to add combobox to CListCtrl header and got ComboBox events
I add combobox to my CTreeListHeader (placed in Dialog Window). How to catch events for this Combo in MFC application?
If I add MFC standard MFC macro
ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(IDC_CMB, &CMFCtestDlg::OnCbnSelChangeCmb)

it does not work, because ComboBox send notification to CTreeList and nno to Dialog Window.
This is example code:
BOOL CMFCtestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CMjAcDialog::OnInitDialog();

    RECT rect;

    m_cTree.InsertColumn(0, L"xxx", 0, 80);
    m_cTree.InsertColumn(1, L"Popis", 0, 180);

    CHeaderCtrl* pHead = m_cTree.GetHeaderCtrl();
    pHead->GetItemRect(0, &rect);

    if (pHead != NULL)
    {
        m_pCombo = new CComboBox;
        RECT cmbRect;
        cmbRect.left = rect.left + 1;
        cmbRect.top = rect.top + 1;
        cmbRect.right = rect.right - 1;
        cmbRect.bottom = rect.top + 14;

        m_pCombo->Create(CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE, cmbRect, pHead, IDC_CMB);

        m_pCombo->GetWindowRect(&cmbRect);
        RECT rect;
        pHead->GetClientRect(&rect);
        pHead->MoveWindow(rect.left, rect.top, (rect.right - rect.left), cmbRect.bottom - cmbRect.top + 2, TRUE);
        pHead->Invalidate();
    }

    TCHAR Planets[9][10] =
    {
        TEXT("Mercury"), TEXT("Venus"), TEXT("Terra"), TEXT("Mars"),
        TEXT("Jupiter"), TEXT("Saturn"), TEXT("Uranus"), TEXT("Neptune"),
        TEXT("Pluto??")
    };

    TCHAR A[16];
    int  k = 0;

    memset(&A, 0, sizeof(A));
    for (k = 0; k <= 8; k += 1)
    {
        wcscpy_s(A, sizeof(A) / sizeof(TCHAR), (TCHAR*)Planets[k]);

        // Add string to combobox.
        ::SendMessage(m_pCombo->GetSafeHwnd(), (UINT)CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)A);
    }

    for (auto const& prvek : *m_pTab)
    {
        int pos = m_cTree.InsertItem(0, L"adfadf");
        m_cTree.SetItemData(pos, (DWORD_PTR)&prvek.first);
        m_cTree.SetItemText(pos, 1, L"asdasd");
    }

    return TRUE;
}


then you need to subclass the CHeaderCtrl ....

Do you mean make a MyCHeaderCtrl and inside it resend the notification message to window?
